# How to structure a PHP app to prevent including a library more than once?

Tags: php, include

Recently I've been facing a specific problem, that of including a file twice (actually a bunch of files twice), but I haven't found the solution to the problem because of the complexity of the system, I've created. Below is the sketch for my file system.

http://flockdraw.com/gallery/view/1976405

See, my main file is connection.php (where the database connection is established), which includes constants.php in another hand. Then I have two files that include connection (and really extend the class, because of different databases and purposes these two files would have): database.php (database operations for users database) and uni_database (database operations for another database I'm using). These two files are used separately by session.php (which uses functions from the database.php class) and uni_class(which uses functions from the uni_database class).

I have to include those two file (uni_class and session.php) to almost any another pages of mine, but when I do so, I include constants and connection twice, which results in errors.

I had a solution to use only one connection to the database, one file for database operations (queries), but then again it doesn't seem logical to me to put the uni_class and session class in one file.

Comment: Use `include_once` or `require_once`, check the manual.

Comment: Use an autoloader, like [SPL_Autoload](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload.php)

Comment: You can use 'function_exists' or check for a definition of a constant to determine whether the file has been included yet.

Comment: I've suggested an edit to this question to reduce the number of tags to a set which make sense for specifics of the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using an autoloader is probably the best solution.  Though you could also use `require_once` or `include_once` as those are built-in functions for PHP that do exactly what you need.

Comment: Thanks, I've added the include_once statement.